# is there an example of AFHTTPClient posting json with AFNetworking?

Tags: afnetworking, jsonkit

Looking for an example of how to post json with `AFHTTPClient`. I see that there is a postPath method which takes an `NSDictionary` and the AFJSONEncode method returns an `NSData`. Is there an easy way to serialize an object to `NSDictionary`, or is there an easier way using jsonkit?

I just need to post the object as json to a REST API.

**UPDATE:** So I tried passing a dictionary over but it seems to break on serializing a nested array.

For example, if I have an object:

```
Post* p = [[Post alloc] init];
p.uname = @"mike";
p.likes =[NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
p.geo = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:37.78583], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-122.406417], nil ];
p.place = @"New York City";
p.caption = @"A test caption";
p.date = [NSDate date];
```

who's get dictionary has data like the following:

```
{
    caption = "A test caption";
    date = "2011-12-13 17:58:37 +0000";
    geo =     (
        "37.78583",
        "-122.4064"
    );
    likes = 1;
    place = "New York City";

}
```

the serialization will either just fail outright or geo will not be serialized as an array but as a string literal like `("37.78583", "-122.4064");`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you're posting to a JSON REST API, there should be a particular mapping from object property to JSON key, right? That is, the server is expecting certain information in certain named fields.

So what you want to do is construct an `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary` with the keys used in the API and their corresponding values. Then, simply pass that dictionary into the `parameters` argument of any request method in `AFHTTPClient`. If the `parameterEncoding` property of the client is set to `AFJSONParameterEncoding`, then the body of the requests will automatically be encoded as JSON.

Comment: Hey Matt, I was trying that earlier and had trouble with a nested nsarray. It seems to work fine until I it takes my geo property which is an NSArray of two NSNumbers.  It will pass that as a quoted string with escaped characters so it is submitted as "(\n  43.1, \n -70.0)"

Comment: Ok, so I was getting that funny formatting if I didn't set json serialization, but with json serialization I get an error in serializing the NSDate.  Can I pass it a date formatter or should I format it to string in the dictionary before I pass it to AFNetworking?

Comment: worked out serializing with jsonkit by passing in a block to handle NSDates into the JSONDataWithOptions method... what's the best way do you think to work that back into the afnetworking request?

Comment: Be sure to use convert `NSDate` into an `NSString` with either a date formatter (check out [ISO8601Formatter](http://boredzo.org/iso8601parser/)), or just by sending `-description`.

Comment: Hey @mattt Can you please have a look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219006/afhttpclient-post-with-json-wrapped-parameters

Comment: @mattt once you add `AFJSONParameterEncoding` I am assuming AFN applies the encoding to every request, am I right? Can we have it applied to certain requests only ?

Answer (score 7):

The best and simple way to do that is to subclass AFHTTPClient.

Use this code snippet

MBHTTPClient

```
#define YOUR_BASE_PATH @"http://sample.com"
#define YOUR_URL @"post.json"
#define ERROR_DOMAIN @"com.sample.url.error"

/**************************************************************************************************/
#pragma mark - Life and Birth

+ (id)sharedHTTPClient
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    __strong static id __httpClient = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        __httpClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:YOUR_BASE_PATH]];
        [__httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
        [__httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        //[__httpClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"" password:@""];
    });
    return __httpClient;
}

/**************************************************************************************************/
#pragma mark - Custom requests

- (void) post<#Objects#>:(NSArray*)objects
success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *request, NSArray *objects))success
failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *request, NSError *error))failure
{
    [self postPath:YOUR_URL
       parameters:objects
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *request, id JSON){
              NSLog(@"getPath request: %@", request.request.URL);

              if(JSON && [JSON isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
              {
                  if(success) {
                      success(request,objects);
                  }
              }
              else {
                  NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:ERROR_DOMAIN code:1 userInfo:nil];
                  if(failure) {
                      failure(request,error);
                  }
              }
          }
          failure:failure];
}
```

Then in your code just call

```
[[MBHTTPClient sharedHTTPClient]  post<#Objects#>:objects
                                          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *request, NSArray *objects) {
    NSLog("OK");
}
                                          failure:(AFHTTPRequestOperation *request, NSError *error){
    NSLog("NOK %@",error);
}
```

objects is an NSArray (you can change it to NSDictonary) and will be encode in JSON format

Comment: doesn't seem to work with the latests versions of AFNetworking. postPath expect a NSDictionary as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestByPostWithNSArrayToJSONArray:(NSArray *)parameters
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"" relativeToURL:self.baseURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:self.defaultHeaders];

    if (parameters)
    {
            NSString *charset = (__bridge NSString *)CFStringConvertEncodingToIANACharSetName(CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(self.stringEncoding));
            NSError *error = nil;

            [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/json; charset=%@", charset] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wassign-enum"
            [request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:0 error:&error]];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@ %@: %@", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), error);
            }
    }

    return request;
}
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL         URLWithString:URL_REGISTER_DEVICE]];
NSArray *array = @[@"hello", @"world"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestByPostWithNSArrayToJSONArray:array];


AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
{
    NSLog(@"network operation succ");

} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"network operation fail");

}];

[operation start];
```

Comment: tried to format your code (not overly successful ;-) - please edit and improve