# AFNetworking: POST request with application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: objective-c, ios, asihttprequest, afnetworking

I'm learning to use `AFNetworking`.

I know I can use `AFHTTPClient` for making a POST request with json.

My question is: is there a way to make a standard POST request (that is, with a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`)? My server backend doesn't accept json, because the client should use the same form for login via web.

In past I used `ASIHTTPRequest` and I used this code:

```
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.example.org/login/"];
request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:self.username forKey:@"username"];
[request setPostValue:self.password forKey:@"password"];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved with `[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFFormURLParameterEncoding];`

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8491782/719127

Answer (score 0):

Just create a [NSMutableURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object and modify the HTTP-headers and body as per Apple documentation. This request object can then be used with the AFNetworking library.